# How do I add a CSS class to an element from CSS (not jquery nor javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want for all images on my webpage to have CSS class "fadeIn" so that when when they first appear, they will fade into view.  (I'm using CSS animations to do the fadeIn.  Later, I use jquery to add and remove the class.)

I'd normal make an img element and use `myImg.addClass("fadeIn")` but the element is made deep within the code of Google Maps and I don't have access to element.  It's also uncertain when the `img` element will actually be created.

Something like this, in CSS:

```
img {
   height: 100;
   width: 50;
   AddClassToThisElement: "fadeIn"  ***
}
```

Is something like this possible?

**Edit**: The actual CSS that I had was:

```
  img[src^="da"] {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInFrames;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  .fadeOut {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutFrames;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
```

The former was more specific so adding class fadeOut to elements didn't work.  By changing `.fadeOut` to `img[src^="da"].fadeOut`, the latter is now more specific and adding fadeOut to the element works.

Comment: I don't believe plain CSS can do this, but take a look at [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). Both support the idea of mixins, which might get you part of the way there.

Comment: CSS cannot do this. You need to use JavaScript.

Comment: SASS and LESS are JavaScript behind the scenes. I can't think of any way of doing this that doesn't involve JS.

Comment: @Utkanos both can be precompiled serverside into standard CSS.

Comment: This is true, but if JS wasn't option for the OP (due to Google maps) I can't see that anything server-side would be, either. Could be wrong.

Comment: if you want all images well select all the images and do your fadeins on them.

Comment: It is total unimportant how "deep" an element is "made" in a 3rd party API. When the element is rendered out to the page, then it is in the dom and you have access to it.

Comment: @SvenBieder--I agree. I questioned this comment of Eyal's as well. Not sure why there is no access, unless the element is created at some later date than page load, by some process of Google Maps, so it is not accessible to have a class appended until such time as it loads, at which point it is already "visible" and the fadeIn is pointless. I think he is trying to target it with a css3 transition so that when it loads, it fades in, without having the class set by jQuery to begin with.

Comment: @SvenBieder: Very true (upvote), but Eyal also mentions that it's unclear *when* the image is created -- and that could definitely matter to JavaScript. If it's added after `$(document).ready()` or `$(window).load()` for example, we've lost our typical hook for these kinds of things.

Comment: If we are talking about the v3 API, then there can be given a callback parameter that is a function name. That means I have an event that trigger after I have loaded, updated, re-rendered, modified (or whatever you do) the map and there I have my hook to the newly created elements.

Comment: @Sven: I have access to the element, but between the creation of the element (Google Maps Marker) and my code to manipulate the DOM, the element flashes on the screen for a moment.  I wanted to avoid that flash.

Comment: @Eyal: can you perhaps make a jsfiddle of it, so that I can see what exactly happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS cannot do this, to the best of my knowledge.

My suggestion, then, is to use something like this:

```
img,
.fadeIn
{
    /* styling */
}
```

Now all images have the same styling as `.fadeIn`. Of course, you'll also have to add `img,` with any relevant (pseudo-)selectors/classes for each use of `.fadeIn` in your style sheet.

Comment: My selectors were "img[src^="da"]" and ".fadeIn".  The first one had a higher specificity so it always overrode fadeIn.  By changing ".fadeIn" to "img[src^="da"].fadeIn", the class can now override the former.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery to do the fade in, you might be able to come up with a selector that is unique to these images rather than using a basic $('.fadeIn') selector.

So if you are doing

```
$('.fadeIn').fadeIn()
```

you might find that there is something in the DOM structure that is unique to those images like

```
$('#SomeMapId div#SomeContainerId IMG').fadeIn()
```

Without seeing your page I couldn't say if the DOM is unique enough to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with DragoonWraith, that if you really want "all images on my webpage" to have this fade effect, then you should be able to target them all more generically. However, if you need more specificity, find out the path. My answer is similar to Leslie Hanks (who posted just before my completing this), except as I understand it, you are not wanting initially to use jQuery, but a css transition. So if you need more specificity, find out the path:

```css
#someGoogleMapId .someDeepContainerClass img {
   /* apply the css transitions */
}
```